# JavaFX Scene Builder Menu object not draggable

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm new to JavaFX and SceneBuilder.
In SB, I'm trying to place a Menu object in a AnchorPane with a drag and drop and this operation is not being possible as no menu object instance is being dragged.
Also, no drag and drop is being allowed also to the Hierarchy pane of the Library accordion.

The AnchorPane is the one placed by default when the tool is started from NetBeans "new - empty FXML".
This problem doesn't exist to other objects, like buttons.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

with:
NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.0.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.7.0_80; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.80-b11
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_80-b15
System: Linux version 3.19.0-58-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)

And:

Product Version
JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0

Build Information
Version: 2.0-b20, Changeset: 5cac093e5c1f
Date: 2014-03-21 09:30

JavaFX
Toolkit = QuantumToolkit
Pipeline = SWPipeline
Hardware acceleration DISABLED

Java
1.8.0-b132, Oracle Corporation

Operating System
Linux, amd64, 3.19.0-58-generic

Any help,please?

Pedro

Answer (score 5):

A [`Menu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Menu.html) is not a `Node`, so you can't put it in an `AnchorPane`. You can only put it in a `MenuBar`. Probably what you want to do is put a `MenuBar` in the `AnchorPane`, and then add `Menu`s to the `MenuBar`. Another option might be to use a [`MenuButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html), depending on exactly what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Many thks James_D. The MenuBar is placed in a different pane and I didn't realize that.